# Gun turret for a Star Wars ship?

Tags: set-identification

Would someone know what set this belongs to?[image]

Answer (score 12):

That would be set [75246 - Death Star Cannon](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75246-1) :

[image]

One of only 4 sets that have a [Trans-Red Dish 3 x 3 Inverted (Radar)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43898#T=C&C=17).